# DropBox Chooser and documentsPicker for Swift developers 3.0

Tags: swift, google-drive-api, dropbox, icloud, uidocumentpickervc

While the **Chooser** implementations for iOS are present [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser#ios). It is however limited to Objective-C. Is it possible to create a chooser in swift manually?

(A dropBox chooser)

[image]

I am also unable to sufficiently call the documentspicker functions, where one can pull any document from any app the user may have installed.

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use any Objective-C library in your Swift app.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/DropBox-Chooser-for-Swift-developers-maybe/m-p/197398#M9083 ]

Comment: For swift 3.0 you can use this https://github.com/Sahilberi/SwiftyDropDataListing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

⭐**Solved**

From your project's capabilites. First enable both the iCloud serivces and the key Sharing, now import MobileCoreServices in your class. Finally extended the following three classes inside your class.

```
UIDocumentMenuDelegate,UIDocumentPickerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

Now implement the following functions..

```
 public func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
              let myURL = url as URL
              print("import result : /(myURL)")
    }


public func documentMenu(_ documentMenu:UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
            print("view was cancelled")
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

How to call all of this? Add the following bit of code to your clickable function..

```
func clickFunction(){

let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
            importMenu.delegate = self
            importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet       
            self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Click your button. The following menu will pop up ..

[image: MenuPicker]

In the case of DropBox. Upon clicking on any item. You will be redirected to your app. And the Url will be printed.

[image]

Manipulate the documentTypes to your need. In my app, Users permitted to Pdf only. So, suit yourself.

`kUTTypePDF`

Also if you feel like customizing your own menu bar. Add the following code and customize your own function inside the handler

```
        importMenu.addOption(withTitle: "Create New Document", image: nil, order: .first, handler: { print("New Doc Requested") })
```

[image]

Enjoy it.

Comment: 'UIDocumentMenuViewController' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: